# how convert sql to Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am new to laravel, I am having trouble converting my sql to Laravel Query.

Example

`INSERT INTO table(field1, field2)   SELECT 'value1', 'value2'  WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM tabla WHERE campo = 'search');`

this is my code

`INSERT INTO siryus.presupuesto_anio    (id, fk_agencia_id, anyo, estado, created_at, updated_at) SELECT 30,4,2020, 'A', '2021-04-21 10:35:01','2021-04-21 10:35:01' WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM presupuesto_anio WHERE fk_agencia_id = '4');`

i want insert only if there is no field with that value. The insert is done only if there are values ​​of the select, and the select will return data only if the WHERE is met.

Inside the WHERE we have a simple SELECT that verifies if the data exists in the table.

I want to convert it to example code

`DB::table('presupuesto_anio') ->join('agencia','presupuesto_anio.fk_agencia_id','agencia.id') ->select('presupuesto_anio.*','agencia.descripcion') ->get();`

Comment: What query builder statements have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

im not understand with your questions, **maybe** this will help:

```
$check = Model::where('id', 4)->first();
if(!$check){
    Model::create({
        'column1' => 'value1',
        'column2' => 'value2'
    });
}
```

Comment: I want to convert it to example code

DB::table('presupuesto_anio') ->join('agencia','presupuesto_anio.fk_agencia_id','agencia.id') ->select('presupuesto_anio.*','agencia.descripcion') ->get();